# How to recreate devices to present responsive sites

Tags: iphone, screenshot, template-design, ipad

I have recently just created a template, and I would like to show it on my site that it is responsive & fluid. I would like to take a few screenshots of my site, and display them on multiple devices such as PC, iPad, iPhone, etc.

Are there any online tools/services that allows me to upload an image, and it frames it with a device of my choice?

This is an example of what I'm looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are templates / stock images of different devices out there on the web (and very easy to find), but the best answer I can give you is that you could easily create what you are looking for in Adobe Photoshop and then save that in your own custom template.

For example, if I wanted to have a template with a Thunderbolt display I could mask a portion of that image and then apply whatever image I wanted behind it. I could then add a lighten layer on top for that gloss realism as you see in your provided photo.

**Step By Step**

1. Download your images / templates. Arrange them however you want.
   [image]
2. Mask the portion of the image you want by marquee-ing a portion and then <kbd>Alt + Clicking</kbd> the mask icon. (A quick way to invert your selection and apply your mask.
   [image: Masked]
3. Place your website image behind your masked layer. Crop and transform if necessary.
4. Add gloss effect by using a gradient with the screen blending mode. ~10% opacity usually does the trick
   [image: Gloss Effect]

What's nice is that you can then save this as a template which you could then easily apply any website screenshots you wanted in less than a minute. And look at you, now you have your own custom template for multiple devices.